# How can I turn a side by side drop-down 2 bulb light fixture into a single hanging light fixture?

Tags: bathroom, light

I’m trying to renovate my bathroom and would love to increase the lighting in my poorly lit bathroom by changing the light fixture that is outdated. First pic is the fixture I have now second picture is an example of what I’m trying to put in its place.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Hi Brittany, we are all confused. Going from two socket to one is not likely to increase the amount of light. What is the objective?

Answer (score 6):

There is an issue with what you want to achieve. The first pic is a ceiling light fixture.   The second pic is the light kit on the underside of a ceiling fan.  The two are not interchangeable.  Further the first pic shows clearly that there are bases for 2 lightbulbs.  The fan light has only 1, so inherently it will not provide more light, which is your goal.

What you need to do is find a ceiling light fixture that meets your need for more light. Removing the existing light fixture will reveal a box and wiring in the ceiling that should be compatible with installing the new fixture.

The new fixture will have instructions as to how it should be installed.  Everything you need should be included with the new fixture.   However be aware some products available online have not been tested and approved by North Americas' certifying agency UL.  These products may not be as complete with instructions and necessary parts. You should avoid them.

We don't know exactly what is in the ceiling box or what new fixture you are to install. However most are straight forward and easy to understand. (Always turn off the power to the fixture before doing any work)

When you are ready to install the new light, should you have any questions make a new post.
Good Luck

Answer (score 4):

1- turn off the power, use plug in lamp to have some light.

2- Loosen the two screws (just loosen do not unscrew)

3- twist the light fixture clockwise and it will come out hanging on the wires

4- making sure there is no power take a picture and disconnect the wires

5- check if the new fixture can be screwed on with existing screws

6- connect the wires as before and screw on the fixture

DONE

Comment: Note that step 1 means "turn off the power _at the circuit breaker_". Simply flipping the switch off is _NOT_ sufficient - it's too easy for someone else to turn it on, or even for you to turn the bathroom switch on _out of habit_ when you walk back in after a short break or a trip to retrieve something you forgot.

Answer (score 3):

This site is not the best place for end-to-end tutorial lessons on how to do this if it's new to you.   Buy a book on beginner DIY electrical work, or find a good web site.  Youtube is great.  What you want to do is covered many times by many excellent teachers on youtube.    (And also covered poorly by many people who are not that good ... you need to be selective).  Spend 10 to 20 hours watching, reading, and learning the basics of electrical safety and how to change outlets, switches, and lights.

Preferably, for your first project, find a friend who has experience to watch and tutor you.

**If you have never done electrical work before this is not a good first project**.   It's beginner level, but working overhead on a ladder adds danger and complexity as does holding up a new light fixture while connecting its wires if you only have two hands.  You should first become *very* comfortable replacing a wall outlet or light switch.  Only when you can do that fluently should you try working overhead.

Then, you'll probably be able to swap out this light with no further questions.  But if you have any, come back here and ask.